# Transferring variable values in SoapUI (basic)

Tags: automated-testing, soapui

I'm firing off a GET request and then using a script assertion to populate a variable:

```
def sValue = responseHolder.getNodeValue("//URL/url/value")
```

I want to store the contents of `sValue` and use it in subsequent test scripts.

I've been trying to get properties working but am having no luck.  I suspect that I've missed something embarassingly fundamental.

Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Comment: Can you please show the sample xml response? It couldn't be working because, `xpath` might be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it.

Assuming this in your test case. There is a step which invoke a soap request and gets the response. Add a `Script Assertion` and below is the script. And what this script does is that it will read the response, checks if it is not a soapfault and extract the required `xpath` value as you desired and saves it at test case level property, say `VALUE_FROM_PREVIOUS_RESPONSE` is property name.

**Script**:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
//asserting if the response is soap fault
assert context.response.toLowerCase().contains('soapfault'), "Response is soap fault"
def holder = new XmlHolder(context.response)
//You need to replace the xpath in below statement
def sValue = holder.getNodeValue('/your/xpath')
//asserting if given xpath has any value
assert sValue, "Xpath does not have any value"
//saving the above value at test case level property VALUE_FROM_PREVIOUS_RESPONSE
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('VALUE_FROM_PREVIOUS_RESPONSE', sValue)
```

In the next test step request, use the above property where ever you need above response value of previous step. That is known as property expansion.

Say, `<yourXmlElement>${#TestCase#VALUE_FROM_PREVIOUS_RESPONSE}</yourXmlElement>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @dave-m, did it help to resolve the issue or still having the problem?